# sqoop import parquet size

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

My problem is, that I have an Oracle table with 500k rows. I set up sqoop to import it to HDFS as a parquet file. I set the  --num-partition parameters to 32, and I get the 32 parquet files, but, one of them is 28 MB large, and the others is just 2-3 KB.

Here is my sqoop command:

```
bin/sqoop import --connect <JDBC> --username <USER> --password <PASSWD> --table <TABLE> --target-dir <TARGET_DIR> -m32 --as-parquetfile --delete-target-dir --outdir <DIR>
```

My question is, what could be the reason for this file sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It means your data is not uniformly distributed.**

I did not see any `--split-by` column in the command. So, assuming splitting is done on the primary key. Splitting is basically done by running range queries simultaneously. One of the range query is fetching maximum data, hence the size 28 MB.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to not split the sqoop job at all, just giving "-m 1". 500K row is not high for a parquet file, moreover; parquet is a splittable file format, so a big parquet file will not be an overhead for mapreduce.